# Rounding differences in sum-of-squares calculation

Tags: r

I'm trying to do variance calculations on columns in the process of assessing clustering (different topic).  In doing so, I came across a nice trick to do this using the base 'var' function.  However, just to be sure it was doing what I thought it should be doing, I compared it to a hand-rolled calculation of variance.  When doing my hand-rolled version, I got almost a 1% difference in calculations.  I know that there are differences due to floating-point precision, but 1% on numbers of this size seems kind of high.

Below is the code I used to check the two calc methods (rather, 3 methods, as i also calculated variance via moments, and it looks like the 'var' calculation uses this moments shortcut).  There is sample data and you can see the differences in the variance calculations.

I am wondering if it is reasonable to assert that a 1% difference in these calculations is high, or not?

Thanks,

Matt

Here is the code:

```
>     # Sample data
>     # This will be 2-d coordinates with pre-defined clusters (treatments)
> dat = rbind(
+             # 4-point cross cluster centered on (2,2)
+         data.frame(grp=1, x=2, y=3),
+         data.frame(grp=1, x=3, y=2),
+         data.frame(grp=1, x=2, y=1),
+         data.frame(grp=1, x=1, y=2),
+             # 2-point dumbbell centered on (-2,-2)
+         data.frame(grp=2, x=-3, y=-2),
+         data.frame(grp=2, x=-1, y=-2),
+             # 3-point equilateral triangle cenetered on (-2,2)
+         data.frame(grp=3, x=-2, y=3),
+         data.frame(grp=3, x=(-2 - sqrt(3)/2), y=-1.5),
+         data.frame(grp=3, x=(-2 + sqrt(3)/2), y=-1.5)
+ )
> 
> 
>     # Compare var calc to hand calc
>     # -----------------------------
> 
>     # Shortcut using existing 'var' function
> var1 = (nrow(dat) - 1) * apply(dat[,-1], 2, var)
> print(var1)
       x        y 
41.05556 37.72222 
> 
>     # Hand-rolled from definition
> centroid = apply(dat[,-1], 2, mean)
> var2 = apply((dat[,-1] - centroid)^2, 2, sum)
> print(var2)
       x        y 
41.46952 37.79630 
> 
>     # Using raw moments
>     # Looks to be same as variance calculation
> var3 = apply(dat[,-1], 2, function(col) length(col) * (mean(col^2) - mean(col)^2))
> print(var3)
       x        y 
41.05556 37.72222 
> 
>     # What is the percent difference?
> calcdiff = (var3 - var2) / var2 * 100
> print(calcdiff)
         x          y 
-0.9982268 -0.1959824
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second definition has a bug. When you do

```
var2 = apply((dat[,-1] - centroid)^2, 2, sum)
```

You're not mean-correcting each column, but subtracting the centroid elements alternately down each column.

Try this instead:

```
var2 = apply((dat[,-1] - matrix(centroid, nrow=nrow(dat), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE))^2, 2, sum)
```